# How to add Images in Dropdown menu in HTML or PHP?

Tags: php, html

How do i add images in dropdown menu HTML using PHP ? I have tried creating background url style in option tag but that isn't working, what other ways i can use to add images inside a dropdown menu.

Comment: you can't add images to a HTML `<select>` element. If you want such a feature then you have to use an extra JavaScript-based plugin (such as Select2, and others) which will render a different structure to give the appearance of dropdownlist, but allowing different types of content such as images. Did you research this at all? It's not hard to discover this fact if you search online a little bit.

Comment: make a `<ul>` and use javascript

Comment: Use <ul><li> insted of select option

Comment: Check this one [https://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ctsCz ]

Comment: Do you want images or icons?

Comment: Refer this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list

Comment: custom Images which are 16x16 dimensions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML: insert image at select tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420781/html-insert-image-at-select-tag)

Comment: No, not working - kekolab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add images in select list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list)

Answer (score 2):

You can easilly do that using HTML5, CSS and Javascript. 
Here is an example - you can also find in in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pdL5rxhg/3/).

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const list   = document.querySelector('#myDropdown');
let classes = list.classList;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  classes.toggle('show');
});
```

```css
ul, li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display:flex;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.list-items{  
  flex-direction: column;
}

.list-items li {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.list-items li .img-container {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;  
  background-color: #edfaff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list-items li .img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<h3>Clickable Dropdown</h3>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <ul class="list-items">
    <li>
      <a href="#home">Home</a> <span class="img-container"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" /></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#about">About</a> <span class="img-container"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506929562872-bb421503ef21?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" /></span>
    </li>
    <li>  
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a> <span class="img-container"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495954484750-af469f2f9be5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" /></span>
    </li>
  </ul>  
  </div>
</div>
```